# How to print Each Items with in a List in New Line Jasper iReport.?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have  a string and List of String Items as a Fileds in my Jasper Report and I have  put them in Detail Band of My report

While Generating Reports it prints like

[image: Current Report]

[image: Overflow]

But I want to print each item in separate line like

[image: Expected Report]

and also like this when it overflows

[image: Expected when Overflow]

Any help...??

Comment: You can use list or subreport

Comment: That's List only @alex

Comment: You can apply the same trick with `String.replace` method

Comment: @AlexK Thanks But when the report data overflows it looks likes this How to avoid that..?